# Schedule cloudwatch and stop the scheduling in between

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a file coming into s3 every hour. But there can be a condition where the file can be late. After the file is received, I need to do some functionalities.

For this I will be schedule cloudwatch that will keep checking the s3 after every 5 mins to check the file using a lambda function. Now, once I receive the file, 
I should stop the cloudwatch to trigger for the rest of the hour and start only after that hour is completed for the next file to come.

Example - The cloudwatch triggers at 12 AM to look for a file but it did not get the file. After 5 mins, at 12:05 AM it triggers again, now we have the file. So, we continue with the rest of the functionality.
But here, the cloud watch is supposed to stop till 1 AM and restart at 1 AM to look for the next file.

Is there a way we can do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is a much better idea to trigger the AWS Lambda function when the file arrives. This can be done by creating an Amazon S3 Event as a trigger for the Lambda function.

This is much simpler than checking for a file every *x* minutes and then deactivating the checking for a period.

Benefits:

- Simpler, easier to maintain
- Responds faster to arrival of file

Comment: The file in s3 comes very frequently. I cannot keep an event in s3 because it will create problems. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What sort of "problems" will it create? In the question, you mention that the file comes every hour, which is not frequent. Nonetheless, the Amazon S3 Event + Lambda combination can handle hundreds of files per second, depending upon the processing time required for the file.

Comment: you can drive s3 events into a sqs for more orderly processing

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add s3 as an event source. Then You will trigger lambda every time file uploaded to s3. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLroz.png)

Open lambda => click to `Add trigger`, Select `S3`

If you still want to do via CloudWatch event. You can create 2 lambdas:

- First lambda: do the job every 5 mins as you want. **But at the end of lambda, you disable the Cloudwatch event**.
- Second lambda: **Run every hour. You run this lambda to enable the Cloudwatch event**, then the Cloudwatch event will continue to trigger the first lambda.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.disable_rule

Comment: Yes I know about this. But is it achievable through cloud functions? Using the approach I mentioned.

Comment: Okay. So, I need to update the 'next ten trigger' function in the cloudwatch everytime trough the second lambda?

Comment: You are right. The simple way is use 2 lambdas and 2 events (every 5 mins, and hourly event).

Comment: How to do that using lambda?

Comment: from the link I sent. You can use boto3 with `enable_rule` and `disable_rule`